# Computer never seems to receive data sent to it through a com port

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to get a Lego Mindstorms NXT to send data such as text or numbers to a computer through a Bluetooth comport. I am using the blueNXT module [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498085/) to send and receive the data. I can send data perfectly, but when I try to receive data that the NXT sent to the computer, the PySerial buffer is always empty, even after the data has been sent multiple times. I googled around a lot but couldn't find an answer or an alternate way to connect to a NXT in Python 3. I have checked that the comport is correct. Here is my code:

```
from blueNXT import Blue
b = Blue(30) # comport number
input('press enter to go')
print(b.s.inWaiting()) # tell me how many bytes are in the buffer
b.close() # close connection
```

I am using Python 3.2 on Windows 7 32bit.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I think it is my fault and I need to have the NXT as the master and the computer as the slave instead of vice versa.

Comment: Clarification: the blueNXT module was created for python 2, it also works in python 3 with some minor edits to struct calls.

Comment: I used to have b.s.flushInput() right after the input call, but removing it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`b.s.flushInput()` discards the content of the buffer.  Therefore, when you call `b.s.inWaiting()` the buffer is empty.

Comment: I was wondering, is this all of your code? It doesn't seem like the code you have shown here would recieve data.  Though I should add I'm not entirely familiar with bluenxt.

Comment: Yes, it is all of my code. BlueNxt does some work behind the scenes. And, the code in my question doesn't actually recieve data, it just checks how much is in the buffer. To actually recieve data, I would replace b.s.inWaiting() with b.get().

Comment: the problem is that the buffer is always empty.

Comment: When I call b = Blue() I pass it 30 as the fist argument. I think that sets the 'comport' paremeter. I'll try that anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I should have relized that. I have an idea or two more. It could be something to do with the send code, or if there are other scripts interacting with the data in the buffer that could clear it that could be the problem. Also, have you tried any possible fixes?  Also the comments are getting long.  Maybe we should clean the comments a bit since niether of us can chat.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking, maybe something in my computer's bluetooth driver is flushing the buffer, or it only accepts input from certain devices. I'll do some googling.